# Sequence controller in DHMTL

Tags: javascript, dhtml

I'm trying to display the below HTML page in Browser. But it shows nothing.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Code Listing 19-4</TITLE>
<OBJECT ID="Seq1" CLASSID="CLSID:B0A6BAE2-AAF0-11D0-A152-00A0C908DB96">
</OBJECT>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
Seq1.Item("ActionSet1").At(0.000,"showText(`3')",1,0.050,1);
Seq1.Item("ActionSet1").At(1.000,"showText(`2')",1,0.050,1);
Seq1.Item("ActionSet1").At(2.000,"showText(`1')",1,0.050,1);
Seq1.Item("ActionSet1").At(3.000,"showText(`Ta Da!')",1,0.050,1);

function showText(obj){ Span1.innerHTML=obj }

</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY onload="Seq1.Item(`ActionSet1').Play()">
<CENTER>
<SPAN ID="Span1" STYLE="font:48pt bold arial;color:red"></SPAN>
</CENTER>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Anyone knows what is the exact issue?